# How to open webcam from the web app and how to store into database and how to apply face recognition algorithm

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing a website. Now i want to add face recognition in my system. Now what will i do? How i strore webcam pic into database and how to analyse that pic in mvc5?

Comment: First rule on this website I had to learn the hard way was to post something I tried not asking for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

A few google searches could have given you the same info i gave you below. Check the [stack overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask question that matches this site's gold standard in terms of questions quality :-)

Never tried to do this myself, bu I've heard about [Emgu](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) ([download](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation)) which is a c# wrapper for [opencv](http://opencv.org/) a

> open source computer vision [...] software library

You could try to implement this library for the face recognition part.

For the Webcam part, try [WebRTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API). It's a javascript, that you should be able to use to take still pictures. Here is a giude on how to do so on [MDM Web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos)

Good luck :-)